# Android:position of an element in a scrollable window

Tags: android

I have 20 buttons in vertical layout in a scrollable window. While click on a button I want to know the position of that button on screen.Some times I click the button after a scrolling.I want the exact position at that time too.What is the code for that.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Never use 20 buttons inside layout. Use listview with button and use onitem click of listview and get button position:

list view onitem click:

```
listId.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
          -------Here position displays **pos**----          
       }
    });
```

Refer this example for a nice [listview](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) sample

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


                System.out.println("this is position"+lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2)



            }
        });
```